# qt doing expensive operations breaks the stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I'm using qt 4.8 with msvc 2015
I designed a with some stylesheet and made an expensive operation in a background thread
when I click the button to start the thread I noticed that the stylesheet is sometimes would be broken
background-color broke in some widgets, border in some widgets, some properties like hover, qprogressbar had a strange chunk ....
this is my operation :

```
for (ULONG i = 0;i < BufferSize; ++i) {
    raw_stream << "0x" << std::hex << int(Buffer[i]); // raw_stream is stringstream;
    if (i+1 != BufferSize) raw_stream << ", ";
    ((MainWindow*)ptr)->progress_signal(i+1); // ptr is a pointer to the main class passed to the function
}
```

I want to print the hex of the files but the operation is very slow and it breaks the stylesheet

I can't say it's because the time it takes as it's running in the background thread so what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Style Sheets had been improved in more resents versions of Qt. Try with the latest version of Qt at [qt.io](http://qt.io).
As intensive tasks blocks the application event loop, some desktop managers like the Windows Explorer blocks graphics updates. So I suggest you to run your intensive code on a separate thread. Also I recommend **not** pass `MainWindow` as a pointer to any class, as it violates the principles of *Domain Driven Design* in most cases, instead I recommend you to use signals and slots.
This is from QtHelp (see QThread in help):

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    void run() override {
        /*
            ... here is the expensive or blocking operation. It will run in paralell ...
            you must emit your reportProgress signal here with the progress of the operation.
        */
        emit resultReady();
    }
signals:
    void reportProgress(int progress);
    void resultReady();
};
```

Then you must create a object of type `WorkerThread` (subclassing `QThread`) in your `MainWindow` class (or in the class you want to) and connect the `reportProgress(int)` signals emitted to the slot where you update the progress, and the `resultReady()` to take actions when the operation finishes. Finally, call the `run()` function on it when you want to start your operation.

**NOTE:** Remember that if you report the progress continuously the events will accumulate in the call stack blocking the event loop and you will get the same result as running your intensive task on the main thread. A workaround could be requesting the progress every 100ms or something like that.

Comment: thanks , I tried without any progress report and didn't get any problem and the operation became much fast , so the problem is in progress report so I'll use signals and slots and paste the result

Comment: I tried qt signals and slots and and reported the progress every 100 bytes , now the function is faster and safer

Comment: I wonder how qt signals and slots differ from ordinary callbacks

Comment: I wonder that too. You can always ask that question. I'm sure it will be well-received. Ok, but consider report every # ms, because on machines with faster hard drives the 100 bytes will be copied even before the event can be processed, and you will get *again* the same problem.

Comment: which problem you talk about , the reporting isn't for reading the file but for converting it

Comment: Ok, sorry then. Just ignore my comment.